# How can i display characters count for each input in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I have first and second inputs in app component and for each different input change i want to display the character count of that particular input / max allowing characters value only on input change and after blur i want to hide the characters count text with dynamic component .

So i created a one component to show and hide for input characters length / max length characters of input by input change and blur events , but in first input box after entering the values in input ..its applying the character count and after entering the values in second input box the characters count is applying first input box, its not applying to the particular input (i.e second input box)

I am attaching the stackblitz url for reference :-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focusinout-event-l5bcow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use another ID for second input

```html
<div>
  <label>Second : </label>
  <br />
  <input
    name="date"
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (input)="charactersLeft2.onInputChange($event)"
    (blur)="charactersLeft2.onBlurChange($event)"
    [maxlength]="5"
  />
  <app-count-character
    #charactersLeft2
    [maxCharacters]="5"
  ></app-count-character>
</div>
```